# how to let Matlab keep a mex session alive

Tags: c++, matlab

My question is on how to program Matlab and my c++ code so that they can interact. To be more specific, I have a c++ program that process data, create an object, derive statistics of that object and write to mat file. I will then load it in matlab to do further analysis and visulization. 
  However, the time it takes to process a data and create the object is enormous, while the time to derive a statistic is negligible. On the other hand, there are many statistics and different combination of them and it is difficult to anticipate what combinations we are going to use. So I hope I can run the "statistics" part interatively many times without repeating the job of processing the data.

My question is: Can I ask Matlab to: 1. call the c++ code; 2. after processing the data and creating the object, keep that object "alive" in the memory 3. call the c++ code again to ask for a statistic to be loaded into my workspace. 4. Repeat 3 with different statistics.
  Thanks

Answer (score 3):

A further option may be to create a C++ class instance in your MEX function and return a pointer to it to MATLAB, passing the pointer to any subsequent calls. You should also create a MATLAB handle class wrapper for it if you use this approach, to allow you to clean up memory properly in its destructor. [Here](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/answers/783) is a post where the poster was advised to do just that, and [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/38964) is an example of the method on the Mathworks FileExchange.

The applicability of this method to your problem depends on the complexity of the problem. I would personally only go down this route if the problem is intractably complex with other approaches (e.g., you need to use a C++ class from some library and the instance must stay alive between calls, or if global variables won't do the trick as you need to keep track of a lot of instances and this is naturally represented best by an array of C++ classes where you can properly separate your concerns).

Answer (score 1):

One way to accomplish this is to declare the variables that you want to access again as [global](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/42-global-variables/) in your c++ [mex code](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/introducing-mex-files.html). These variables will stay in the memory and you can access them again (when you call your mex function) until you clear that mex function or close the Matlab session. I used global variables for this purpose and it worked just fine for me.

Another option is to use [persistent variables](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/persistent.html). From the documentation

> Persistent variables are similar to global variables because the
>   MATLAB® software creates permanent storage for both. They differ from
>   global variables in that persistent variables are known only to the
>   function in which they are declared. This prevents persistent
>   variables from being changed by other functions or from the MATLAB
>   command line.